# Consulta en mysql mediante un select

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola muy buen día quien me puede orientar un poco
Quiero hacer un select pero mediante a ese select hacer una consulta a mysql y me muestre datos en recuadros quien me puede orientar un poco en como realizar esa función muchas gracias

EJEMPLO

BD

| ID | ARTICULO | TIPO | IMPORTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | ADMI | 100 |
| 2 | 10000 | OPE | 60 |
| 3 | 10000 | OPE | 120 |
| 4 | 10001 | ADMI | 150 |

CONSULTA

```sql
SELECT SUM(if(ARTICULO='10001',importe,0)) Suma1
FROM gastos
WHERE tipo='ADMI'
UNION
SELECT SUM(if(ARTICULO='10000',importe,0)) Suma2
FROM gastos
WHERE tipo='OPE';
```

EJEMPLO HTML

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<select  style="width:230px">
<option>Selecciona Articulo</option>
<?php
$query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM bd ORDER BY ARTICULO DESC");
while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
echo '<option value="'.$valores[ARTICULO].'">'.$valores[ARTICULO].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<td><table><B>suma1</B></table></td>
<td><table><B>suma2</B></table></td>
<td><table><B>suma3</B></table></td>
</body>
</html
```

> 

Es como para hacer un concentrado general
Muchas gracias

Comment: No se termina de entender, ¿cuál es el problema?, ¿cuál es la salida de datos que esperas?, ¿qué error da esta consulta que ya tienes?

Comment: Quiero mostrar los resultados de la consulta SQL en la tabla por ejemplo la consulta de suma condicional suma1 en el campo de la tabla suma1 y a si sucesiva pero la consulta sea automática con el select de articulo

Comment: ¿Por qué uno usas un `GROUP BY` en vez de ese `IF` con `UNION`? ¿Qué resultado esperas de esa consulta? ¿Sabes cómo pasar los resultados de la consulta a la tabla? ¿Dónde usas el dato del desplegable?

Comment: Es lo que quiero consultarme como hacerlo para que sea factible

Answer (score 0):

Te he arreglado un poco lo que has hecho, pero no termino de entender qué necesitas exactamente:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<select  style="width:230px">
<option>Selecciona Articulo</option>
<?php
$rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT ARTICULO FROM gastos ORDER BY ARTICULO DESC;");
while ($valores = $rs->fetch_array()) {
echo '<option value="'.$valores['ARTICULO'].'">'.$valores['ARTICULO'].'</option>';
}
$rs=$mysqli->query("
    SELECT SUM(if(ARTICULO='10001',importe,0)) Suma1
      FROM gastos
      WHERE tipo='ADMI'
      UNION
      SELECT SUM(if(ARTICULO='10000',importe,0)) Suma2
      FROM gastos
      WHERE tipo='OPE';
")->fetch_all();
?>
</select>
<table>
<tr>
<td><B><?=$rs[0][0]?></B></td>
<td><B><?=$rs[1][0]?></B></td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE gastos(
  ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ARTICULO int,
  TIPO varchar(4),
  IMPORTE float
  );
INSERT INTO gastos (ARTICULO, TIPO, IMPORTE) VALUES
(10001,'ADMI',100),
(10000,'OPE',60),
(10000,'OPE',120),
(10001,'ADMI',150);
```

Obtengo:

```
250
180
```

Déjame más indicaciones modificando tu pregunta o en los comentarios

Comment: Si es algo a si pero ase cuenta que en un select seleccione el id y automáticamente me haga las consultas en una tabla me muestre al lado izquierdo suma1 y al derecho suma2 y muchas gracias por tu tiempo de revisar mi pregunta gracias

Comment: Modifico la respuesta, a ver si ahora he logrado entenderte

Comment: Muchas gracias David

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Comment: Si en pocas palabras lo que quiero hacer es en base a un select hacer 2,3 a 4 consultas en sql y mostrar las en un txt por ejemplo si en el select selecciono el Articulo=10001 que me haga la consulta de suma condicional don admi y en otro txt la suma condicional con op algo así